# How to search a word in a dictionary with a document in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I have created a dictionary of words. Now I need to check whether the word in the dictionary is present in the document or not. The sample of the document is given below:

```
Laparoscopic surgery, also called minimally invasive surgery (MIS), bandaid surgery, or keyhole surgery, is a modern surgical technique in which operations are performed far from their location through small incisions (usually 0.5–1.5 cm) elsewhere in the body.

There are a number of advantages to the patient with laparoscopic surgery versus the more common, open procedure. Pain and hemorrhaging are reduced due to smaller incisions and recovery times are shorter. The key element in laparoscopic surgery is the use of a laparoscope, a long fiber optic cable system which allows viewing of the affected area by snaking the cable from a more distant, but more easily accessible location.
```

From this document, I have split each paragraph into each sentence as follows:

```
[1] "Laparoscopic surgery, also called minimally invasive surgery (MIS), bandaid surgery, or keyhole surgery, is a modern surgical technique in which operations are performed far from their location through small incisions (usually 0.5–1.5 cm) elsewhere in the body."
[2] "There are a number of advantages to the patient with laparoscopic surgery versus the more common, open procedure."                                                          
[3] "Pain and hemorrhaging are reduced due to smaller incisions and recovery times are shorter."                                                                    
[4] "The key element in laparoscopic surgery is the use of a laparoscope, a long fiber optic cable system which allows viewing of the affected area by snaking the cable from a more distant, but more easily accessible location."
```

The dictionary includes the following words:

```
Laparoscopic surgery
minimally invasive surgery
bandaid surgery
keyhole surgery
surgical technique
small incisions
fiber optic cable system
```

Now I want to search for all words in the dictionary with those in each sentence using R? The code that I have worked out is given below.

```
c <- "Laparoscopic surgery, also called minimally invasive surgery (MIS), bandaid surgery, or keyhole surgery, is a modern surgical technique in which operations are performed far from their location through small incisions (usually 0.5–1.5 cm) elsewhere in the body.

   There are a number of advantages to the patient with laparoscopic surgery versus the more common, open procedure. Pain and hemorrhaging are reduced due to smaller incisions and recovery times are shorter. The key element in laparoscopic surgery is the use of a laparoscope, a long fiber optic cable system which allows viewing of the affected area by snaking the cable from a more distant, but more easily accessible location."

library(tm)
library(openNLP)

convert_text_to_sentences <- function(text, lang = "en") {
sentence_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(language = lang)
text <- as.String(text)
sentence.boundaries <- annotate(text, sentence_token_annotator)
sentences <- text[sentence.boundaries]
return(sentences)
}

q <- convert_text_to_sentences(c)
```

Comment: You want to search for each word individually or each phrase exactly?

Comment: I want to search for each phrase in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming q is a character vector (or list) of the sentences and you're interested in exact matches of the keywords only, then you can use regular expressions:

```
matches = lapply(q, function(x) dict[sapply(dict, grepl, x, ignore.case=T)])
```

You get a list of the length of q. Every list element contains a vector of the dictionary words found in the according sentence.

Comment: This works....But it gives me only integers. I want to retrieve those exact words from the document

Comment: This is not the expected output. Here q is not a character vector. q indicates sentences after tokenization

Comment: In fact, your q is a character vector, try str(q). I edited my answer, so that you have a list of the length of q, with the words found in every sentence of q.